How to use tkinter .get() function
I started learning tkinter yesterday, but thanks to a really good series of you tube videos I have progressed quite well. However, when I try to run my code:My code and press the run button it gives the error: The error. Any idea's why it doesn't work would be much appreciated.
I have tried various ways, including changing variable names and random attributes like the length or the borderwidth.

Please always post all errors and code and text. The problem though is grid returns None, and you're assigning that to GOCbox.

You can't create a widget and add it to  the display on one line, the way you are doing it. If you are determined to put it on one line, you will have to use a walrus, and encase the widget declaration in parens: (lbl := Label(...)).grid(...)
